# Check if an element is visible if it is hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to show a search box when you click the search icon in WordPress.  The issue I am having is I want it to hide if you click anyplace else on the site.

Currently this is the code I am using and it works if you click the icon on and off but i want lost focus click also.

```js
<script>
  function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
          x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "block";
      }
  }
</script>
```

The other script I was trying to use is this but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```js
<script>
    document.addEventListener('click', function handleClickOutsideBox(event) {
        const box = document.getElementById('myDIV');
        if (window.getComputedStyle(x).visibility === "visible") {
            x.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be great thank you.

The second part of my code

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('click', function handleClickOutsideBox(event) {
      const box = document.getElementById('myDIV');

      if (window.getComputedStyle(x).visibility === "visible") {
          x.style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
  });
</script>
```

I thought this would hide it if it saw it was visible but it isn't working.

Comment: You don't actually need to check whether it's visible or not; you can just hide the element. If it's already hidden, nothing will happen.   (Just decide whether you're wanting to use `display` or `visibility` to hide it; either will work, but they aren't interchangeable.)

Comment: *Check if an element is visible* - as tagged [tag:jquery] (despite not using jquery...maybe remove that tag if you don't want jQuery solutions) - use [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
function toggle() {
  var input = document.querySelector("input");
  input.classList.toggle("hidden");
  if (input.style.visibility != "hidden") input.focus();
}
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
  toggle();
});
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  toggle();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">Open
</button>
<input name="search" class="hidden" placeholder="Enter search here"/>
```

Setting both display and visibility as I've shown here is overkill. You only need one of them (they do slightly different things in this context)

Comment: So th issue with this is it is the same thing I have going on.  I want the search box to hide when I click anyplce on the page outside of inside of the search box.

Comment: @KirkSturgulewski that's what the "blur" event is for. Try clicking into and then out of the search box.

Comment: @KirkSturgulewski I've updated the code so that the focus is automatically requested by the search box. So now any outside click will hide it

Comment: @KirkSturgulewski Has this solved your problem? If so, please click the checkmark next to this answer to mark the question as answered.

Comment: I am still having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing 'visibility' to 'display' in your second and third code pieces.

because you're controlling your search inputs' visibility using 'display' attribute in the first piece so the 'visibility' is quite meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  I ended up using this.

```
 <script>
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
       var container = document.getElementById('container');
        if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
          container.style.display = 'none';
             }
          });

  </script>
```